# Making hotkeys for configurable shortcuts in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, autohotkey

I have shortcuts within Outlook 2010, but I don't like that the combos within are three button combos (Ctrl+Shift+9). So, I want to have hotkeys to those shortcuts when Outlook is active. My code is below, why isn't it working?

```
;++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++;
;OutlookShortcuts;                     
SetTitleMatchMode, 2                   
GroupAdd, shortcut, - Microsoft Outlook   
#IfWinActive, ahk_group shortcut
!c::^+7 ;move to inbox;
!d::^+6 ;mark as unread;                            
!e::^+5 ;mark as read;
return
```

Comment: What isn't working? Does the script run? Does it give an error? Shortcuts do nothing?

Comment: It doesn't do anything actually. The hotkeys don't work and there is no error prompt or anything like that. But, this is just a portion of a bigger script and nothing after this section of the script runs correctly.

Comment: Close your `#IfWinActive` with an `#If` at the end.  Also add a hotkey that does a simple `msgbox` to ensure your `#IfWinActive` is working correctly.

Comment: @Dude, please make your own answer to show what has worked for you instead of editing another's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try it like this:

```
;++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++;
;OutlookShortcuts;                     
SetTitleMatchMode, 2                   
GroupAdd, shortcut, ahk_exe Outlook.exe   
#IfWinActive, ahk_group shortcut
!c::^+7 ;move to inbox;
!d::^+6 ;mark as unread;                            
!e::^+5 ;mark as read;
#If
```

Using `ahk_exe` for specifying windows has proven to be extremely helpful for me. I don't think `return` can be used to end an `#If something` region. I'm a little surprised that it doesn't throw an error.
Good luck! Let us know if it's still not working.

Comment: I used a version of this to get it to work! See below for what I exactly used.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gunr2171! The code below is what worked for me! It is nearly the same as @Paul's just with one uneccessary line taken out and the next line has an edit.

```
;++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++;
;OutlookShortcuts;                     
SetTitleMatchMode, 2                     
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Outlook.exe
+c::^+7 ;move to inbox;
+d::^+6 ;mark as unread;                            
+e::^+5 ;mark as read;
#If

;======================================;
```